# Finding an infinite regular language from the difference of two non-regular languages.

Tags: computer-science, education, computability, regular-language

Next Tuesday I'll have to orally discuss a test that I did a few days ago with my Theoretical Computer Science professor. In the test, there was an exercise that I couldn't solve that stated:

> Specify two non-regular languages $L_2$ and $L_3$ on the alphabet $\{a,b\}$, so that $L_2 \setminus L_3$ is infinite and regular.

I know that regular languages are closed under union, intersection and complement but I just can't figure out how to apply the property in this case.

Comment: Can you find a regular language $L$ and a non-regular language $L_2$ such that $L\cap L_2=\emptyset$? Because, taking $L_3:=L\cup L_2$ it follows that $L_3$ is non-regular (or, otherwise, $L_2=L_3\setminus L$ would be regular!), and this gives you the desired example.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Okay, I've tried to choose $L=\{ a^n | n \ge 0 \}$ (which is regular and infinite) and $L_3=\{ a^n b^n | n \gt 0 \}$ (which is non-regular). $L \cap L_3$ should be equal to $\emptyset$ (correct me if I'm wrong). $L \cup L_3 = \{a^n b^m | (n,m \gt 0 \land m = n) \lor (m = 0 \land n \ge 0)\} = L_2$ is, as you said, non-regular. In this way $L_2 \setminus L_3 = L$. Did I got everything right?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Thank you so much, I got it now!